# SocketIO Leave Room and join new Room Logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to know how can I leave the Room when I clicked new Room

My Page is look like this.

[image]

List of the left side are from the MySQL Server and it gets list of my chats. And each Room name has id value which is room name. And it also has onclick function to use function in client side.

I thought when I clicked each Room name and run the joinChat() function and Inside the joinChat() Function

1. Use JoinRoom Socket
2. In Server Side Run `` socket.leave(`${data.joinedRoomName}`); ``
3. And then join new Clicked Room with `` socket.join(`${data.joinedRoomName}`); `` Code

But I don't know How can I pass the current room name when I click the new room. So there's problem from step 2.

So it's look like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="joinChat()">
<h5 id="sangumee-Quarterican-KJ">sangumee</h5>
</a>
```

[Client Side Code]

```
var socket = io.connect('http://118.35.126.220:3001');
function joinChat() {
    let joinedRoomName = window.event.target.id;    // Get clicked id (ROOM NAME)
    $('.msg_history').empty();  // to Remove Previous Chats
    socket.emit('JoinRoom', {
        joinedRoomName: joinedRoomName
    });
    console.log(`Joined : ${joinedRoomName}`);
    $('#chat').on('submit', function (e) {  // Submit Event
        var msg = $('#message').val();  // Get entered Message
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent reload the page
        if (!msg) return; // If no Message return
        $('#message').val('')   // To clean chat input
        socket.emit('send:message', {
            message: msg,
            userId: userId,
            loginedId: loginedId,
            joinedRoomName: joinedRoomName
        });
        // Draw to Outgoing side Chat (Send by me)
        $('.msg_history').append(`<div class="outgoing_msg"><div class="sent_msg"><p>${msg}</p><span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div></div>`);
    });
}

socket.on('receive:message', function (data) {
    console.log(`${data.userId} : ${userId}`)
    if (data.userId != userId) {
        // Draw to Incoming Side Chat (Send by another person)
        $('.msg_history').append(`<div class="incoming_msg"><div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"></div><div class="received_msg"><div class="received_withd_msg"><p>${data.message}</p><span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div></div></div>`);
    }
});
```

[Server Side Code]

```
/* MyPage User Chat Room */
router.get(`/:userId/admin/contact`, function (req, res, next) {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let loginedId = req.user.login;
  db.query(`SELECT * FROM chatRoom WHERE chatReceiver=? OR chatSender=?`, [userId, userId], function (error, room) {
    if (error) {
      throw `Error From /:userId/admin/contact ROUTER \n ERROR : ${error}`;
    }
    console.log(`Room : ${room}`);
    res.render('mypage/contact', {
      userId: userId,
      loginedId: loginedId,
      room: room
      // contactArray: contactArray
    })
  });
});

// Socket IO 
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // Join Room
  socket.on('JoinRoom', function (data) {
    socket.leave(`${data.joinedRoomName}`);
    console.log(`DATA : ${data.joinedRoomName}`)
    socket.join(`${data.joinedRoomName}`);
    console.log(`NEW JOIN IN ${data.joinedRoomName}`)
  })
  socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
    io.sockets.to(`${data.joinedRoomName}`).emit('receive:message', data);
    console.log(`Message Send to : ${data.joinedRoomName}`)
    console.log(`Message Content : ${data.userId} : ${data.message}`);
    // Save Message In DB
    db.query(`INSERT INTO chatData (roomName, chatSender, chatMessage) VALUES (?,?,?)`,[data.joinedRoomName, data.userId, data.message])
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just unjoin every other room when the socket tries to join another room:

```
 Object.keys(socket.room)
  .filter(it => it !== socket.id)
  .forEach(id => socket.leave(id));
```

Or you just keep a variable on the client (or server):

```
 let current;
```

Then if you join, send that to the server and refresh that:

```
socket.emit('JoinRoom', {
    joinedRoomName,
    leave: current,
});

current = joinedRoomName;
```